# Scope a model using several queries, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I am very new to rails.

I have an app that has participants and participant categories.  I am creating a named scopes for participants that fall in to either category "1" or category "8".  I want an either/or type query.  This seems very basic...but I've had the hardest time finding the answer on SO.

Here's where I am right now:

```
scope :organizer, -> { where(cat_id: 1 or cat_id: 8)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :organizer, -> { where('cat_id = ? or cat_id = ?', 1, 8) }
```

What wrong here:

You try mix `SQL` operator `OR` and ruby method invoke.

for future research test query in `rails console`:

```
=> User.where(first_name: 'Foo').to_sql
#> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"first_name\" = 'Foo'"
=> User.where(first_name: 'Foo' or last_name: 'faw').to_sql
SyntaxError: unexpected keyword_or, expecting ')'
User.where(first_name: 'Foo' or last_name: 'faw').to_sql
                           ^
```

Comment: Yes!  I've seen that kind of query around and now I know exactly what it's for.  Thanks.  Accepting asap.